# Building a box plot from all columns of data frame with column names on x in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame `my.df` of the following structure:

```
   A B  C
1  1 1  2
2  2 3  4
3  3 5  6
4 NA 7  8
5 NA 9 NA
```

How to build a box plot from it with column names on x axis and all the values on y?

There are many answers like:

```
ggplot(melt(my.df), aes(variable, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

But I don't understand, what I actually should pass as "variable" and "value". I tried `x=colnames(my.df))` and this partially works, however I still have no idea what to do with y.

Comment: Look at the output when you use `melt(df)` and you will see what is meant by "variable" and "value". (you have to load reshape2 for that to work).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `stack` to transform the data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(stack(df), aes(x = ind, y = values)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. But do you also know, how then to keep the order of columns? They are sorted alphabetically, however, I would like to preserve the existing order from original data frame (for example, B A C).

Comment: @Roman `ggplot(stack(df), aes(x = factor(ind, levels = names(df)), y = values)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: And how could you order it by values? I mean, from the lower the boxplot to the highest?

Comment: You can reorder the df `df <- df %>% relocate(B, .before = A)`